# Как использовать файлы ресурсов в приложение на Java

Tags: java, eclipse, аудио, проект

Столкнулся с проблемой, что совершенно не представляю себе, как вшить в свое приложение, написанное на Java некий звуковой файл, который приложение будет по ходу работы проигрывать. Т.е. как в проекте под Eclipse внедрить файл как "собственный ресурс" приложения и как его затем в коде использовать как обычный файл (стандартными потоками ввода-вывода так сказать).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Доступ к ресурсам jar файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1153337/%d0%94%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc-jar-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Как же это дубликат, если задан аж в 11 году, а тот другой месяц назад?

Comment: @RomanKonoval, если вопросы об одном и том же, не играет существенной роли, какой из них закрыть (перекрёстные ссылки будут присутствовать и там и там). выбор тут уже диктуется качеством ответа: оставить открытым стоит тот, на который дан более детальный ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("myfile")
```

выдаст вам файл `myfile` лежащий рядом с классом `MyClass`.

Comment: Спасибо. Так работает