# Доступ к ресурсам jar файла

Tags: java, maven, resources, jdk11

Есть maven проект java 11. Необходимо получить доступ к ресурсам.

```java
URL url = Main.class.getResource("/file.xml");
File file = new File(url.getFile());
System.out.println(file.exists());
```

При запуске в IDE (Idea) всё работает. Вывод будет True.
Если же собрать jar файл и запустить его `java.exe -jar Example.jar`, то файл не находит, вывод False.

Файл `file.xml` лежит в папка `src/main/resources`, в `pom.xml` добавлено:

```xml
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

и

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>org.example.Main</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

В чём проблема и как её решить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В настройках `pom.xml` надо указать расположение папки с ресурсами и в какую папку их копировать в архиве:

```xml
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <targetPath>resources</targetPath>
  </resource>
  . . .
</resources>
```

Далее прочитать файл, если это текст, можно следующим образом:

```java
InputStream inputStream = Test.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/file.xml");
byte[] bytes = inputStream.readAllBytes();
String text = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println(text); // выводим результат
```

---

Ресурсы могут быть разными, например картинками: [maven сборка jar файла с картинками](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1119031/328896)